# Wy doesn't my VBScript do the same thing on Windows 10 as it does on Windows 7?

Tags: vbscript

I've created a batch file that runs some VBScript which works fine in Windows 7 but not in Windows 10.  Why doesn't it not work on both?

The batch file does 6 things which are listed below.  On Windows 7 all 6 things happen.  On Windows 10 all but item 5 take place and the window title is not changed.

1. opens Internet Explorer
2. brings the window to the foreground
3. navigates to a webpage
4. waits 1.5 seconds to allow the webpage to load
5. changes the window title from "MultiSmart" to "Community MultiSmart"
6. exits

Here is the the batch file.

```
<!-- :
@echo off
cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" %*
exit /b
-->

<job>
  <script language="VBScript">

  Set ie = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

   'ie properties

    ie.ToolBar = 0
    ie.StatusBar = 0
    ie.Width = 816
    ie.Height = 519
    ie.Visible = 1
    ie.Resizable = 0

   'bring window to foreground
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate "Internet Explorer"

   'navigate to Stony Mountain Lift Station's Multismart
    ie.Navigate("http://192.168.0.11/")

   'wait for page to load into browser
    Wscript.Sleep 1500

   'change window title
    ie.document.title="Community MultiSmart"

  </script>
</job>
```

Comment: because it depends on the internet explorer version.Add metadata to force old browser behavior on windows 10.

Comment: Will give this a try & update with results.

Comment: What you have there is not a batch file, but a mix of batch and wsh script. I strongly recommend avoiding Frankenscripts like that.

Comment: thanks npocmaka 

regarding my question - yes, the versions were different
works on IE 11.0.966.18920 but not on IE 11.461.16299.0

regarding my problem - I don't have access to the html so I'll have to find another solution

Comment: npocmaka, please re-post your comment as an answer so I may accept it.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm re-posting npocmaka's comment which answered my question as an answer.

> because it depends on the internet explorer version

The versions were different.  What worked on IE 11.0.966.18920 did not on IE 11.461.16299.0.

Answer (score 1):

I would double check that the webpage is fully loaded.

Change this line:

```
Wscript.Sleep 1500
```

to

```
While IE.ReadyState < 4
    Wscript.Sleep 250
Wend
```

---

> <sub>It's unclear as to whether [npocmaka's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53820523/wy-doesnt-my-vbscript-do-the-same-thing-on-windows-10-as-it-does-on-windows-7#comment94490879_53820523) of:</sub>
> <sub>*"...Add metadata to force old browser behavior on windows 10."*</sub>
>
> <sub>worked for you or not. **If not**, then consider this alternative:</sub>

Check your security settings in IE.

> **Warning:** This answer provides suggestions that may lower your system's security settings. It is advised that you fully understand the risks involved before proceeding and be proactive with using alternative protective measures. *(Or, just stop automating in IE ☺)*

- Go to `IE > Internet Options > Security Tab`
- *(Optional)* Add the website to your 'Trusted Sites' zone if you trust the site *(which will make the next step easier on you)*
- Whichever zone you decided to keep site in (either 'Internet' or 'Trusted Sites'), uncheck the box: <kbd>Enable Protected Mode (requires restart)</kbd>. **Warning**: This is obviously going to reduce the security of IE.

  - Click Apply then OK
- Close out of **ALL IE BROWSERS** to ensure that the change takes effect

  - Double check Task Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd>) to ensure no hidden `iexplore.exe` processes exist in the `Processes` tab.
- Test the end result

  - If still doesn't work, ensure you reverse any settings.

*Scripting can obviously be dangerous to any system, which is why Protected mode may severely limit what you can do with automation. I believe that IE didn't enable protected mode in IE by default until Windows 8(.1)?, but I don't have a source for my suspicions; if this is the case, that would be why it works on Windows 7 and not Windows 10.*

You can still do simple things with protected mode enabled, but it's severely limited. For example, you can still navigate to web pages, but many of IE's other properties and methods are disabled.

Comment: thanks K Davis - I'll test this when I next have access to the system but that won't be until the Christmas break

Comment: I've added the while loop to my wscript and added 192.168.0.11 to my 'Trusted Sites'.  I'm still unable to change the window title with IE 11.461.16299.0 on Windows 10.  This does work very well with IE 11.0.966.18920 on Windows 7.

Comment: FYI, I've edited my hosts file and so IE will display the hostname as a window title instead a bare IP address.  My original question about differences between Windows 7 & 10 is answered.